# Custom dashboard functionality

Tags: powerbi

We are in an early stage of trying to understand PowerBI capabilities, and need to know if or how PowerBi can be incorporated into a custom solution.

Can PowerBI dashboards be customized in such that additional functionality can be added to the UI components?

For example, if we wanted to add a feature to the PowerBI custom UI allowing the user to run an operation on the underlying data belonging to a slice in a pie chart, how can that be achieved? To illustrate, would it be possible to add a context menu item to a pie chart of users divided by age group, so that whenever a slice was right clicked, an option "Email these users" could be applied, calling a back end function to email that subset of users?

If this cannot be done via dashboards, can this be done by incorporating PowerBI components in a custom web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That a good question. Not yet, it's something we've heard from other customers.  Two things more directly.  First, we're opening up our visuals so you'll be able to add custom visuals to your deployments (we've not yet announced how or when, but you can start now by learning how to code against the open source repository.  Here's the vision (marketing for this) https://powerbi.microsoft.com/custom-visuals; Here's the open source repository http://www.github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals.

But you want something more integrated and less custom I think.  Could you submit an idea at http://support.powerbi.com so we can track it and give you updates when we have something like that available?

Comment: Yes, essentially PowerBI would be the main OEM component in a platform resold to customers. We are working on a startup project and trying to differentiate PowerBI from the competition. There are two questions, one is centered on pricing and structures and how we as resellers fit in, being addressed with MS reps right now, and the other is more to do with how we can marry PowerBI with some of the bespoke functions we need to offer. It might help in our case, because it's a startup project, if we had insight into the dev roadmap. Is this available?